# socket.io client does not react on server side

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I try to listen on a socket.io connection on server side but it seems like the client never connects to the server because there are no log messages which appear in the command line.

This is the source I have so far:

```
var socketIoClient = require('socket.io-client');

var client = socketIoClient('http://localhost:3000');

client.on('connect', function(socket){
    console.log('Client connected.');

    // Disconnect listener
    socket.on('disconnect', function() {
        console.log('Client disconnected.');
    });
});

client.on('chat message', function(msg){
    console.log(msg);
});
```

And this is my socket.io server code:

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
var ioSession = require('express-socket.io-session');
var session = require('express-session');
var redis = require('redis');
var redisStore = require('connect-redis')(session);
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var passport = require('passport');
var passportLocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
var uuid = require('uuid');
var connectEnsureLogin = require('connect-ensure-login');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var passportSocketIo = require('passport.socketio');

var userStore = {};

passport.use(new passportLocalStrategy(function(username, password, cb) {
  //if (!user) { return cb(null, false); }
  if (username != password) { return cb(null, false); }
  var user = {
      id: uuid.v4(),
      username: username
  };
  userStore[user.id] = user;

  return cb(null, user);
}));

passport.serializeUser(function(user, cb) {
  cb(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(id, cb) {
  if (!userStore.hasOwnProperty(id)) { return cb('Fehler'); }
  cb(null, userStore[id]);
});

var redisClient = redis.createClient();
var sessionStore = new redisStore({
    client: redisClient
});

var sessionObject = session({
    secret: "my-secret",
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    store: sessionStore
});

// Configure view engine to render EJS templates.
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(sessionObject);

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

app.get('/', connectEnsureLogin.ensureLoggedIn(), function(req, res) {
  res.render('index', { user: req.user });
});

app.get('/login', function(req, res){
    res.render('login');
});

app.post('/login',
  passport.authenticate('local', { failureRedirect: '/login' }),
  function(req, res) {
    res.redirect('/');
  }
);

// SOCKET HANDLING

io.on('connection', function(socket){
  console.log('a user connected ' + socket.handshake.session.id);

  socket.on('disconnect', function(){
      console.log('user disconnected ' + socket.handshake.session.id);
  });

  socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
    var username = socket.request.user.username;
    io.emit('chat message',  username + ': ' + msg);
  });

  socket.on('login', function (data) {
      console.log('login attempt with: ' + data.username + ':' + data.password);
  })
});

io.use(ioSession(sessionObject, {
    autoSave: true
}));

io.use(passportSocketIo.authorize({
  cookieParser: cookieParser,       // the same middleware you registrer in express
  key:          'connect.sid',       // the name of the cookie where express/connect stores its session_id
  secret:       'my-secret',    // the session_secret to parse the cookie
  store:        sessionStore,        // we NEED to use a sessionstore. no memorystore please
}));

http.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

Do I miss anything important?

Comment: Where's your socket.io server code?

Comment: @SlashmanX added the socket.io server code.